# Centralised mailto email link

Tags: email, mailto

Is there a way to centralise a typical mailto html string so that the email address can be updated once instead of multiple times across the pages themselves?

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP with `$_SESSION` you can have a `$mail` variable set that you spread trough all your webpages.

Example :

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["mail"]=YOUR_MAIL_ADDRESS;
?>
...
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_SESSION["mail"] ?>?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

**PageX.php**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 <a href="mailto:<?php echo $_SESSION["mail"] ?>?Subject=Hello%20again"
```

Make just sure that you call this on the top of every pages you want to use this variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

You can read more here :
http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Its there a non-PHP way? System administrators have limited us from enabling it unfortunately.